# Why PORT D pin 15 LED not turning on, in STM32F407 Discovery

Tags: stm32, keil

I am trying to turn on a LED for STM32F407 Discovery which is PORT D pin 15, as shown in the diagram below and the link attached to it.

I am using Keil and an ST-Link debugger setting as shown below.

My STM32 Discovery is connected as shown in the photo below.

I have written a simple code by the registers table shown below to put VDD on PD15, but nothing happens when I flash the program.

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks.

https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

https://rusefi.com/wiki/images/7/7c/Stm32f4discovery_schematics.pdf

```
#include "stm32f407xx.h"

int main()
{ 
    
    GPIOD->MODER&=~(1uL<<31);//reset 0 on 31,     01 to gpio_moder 31,30 bits in register
    GPIOD->MODER|=(1uL<<30);//set 1 on 30 output mode for pin 15 port D
    
    GPIOD->OTYPER=0; //all register is push pull
    GPIOD->OSPEEDR=0;//speed low
    GPIOD->ODR|=(1<<15); //Sets pin 15 as high
    
    
}
```

[image: Build output from Keil]

[image: Photo of STM32 Discovery board]

[image: Part of STM32F4Discovery schematic showing LEDs]

[image: Keil Build Option settings]

Comment: I suggest to use the HAL libraries, that prevents you from all the register bit magic...

Answer (score 3):

You need to activate GPIOD clock before accessing its registers. Also, documentation mentions that you may need to wait for a while after enabling the clock, before accessing the related registers.

```
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN; // Activate the clock
__DSB(); // stall the CPU pipeline until the instruction is completed
```

Also, don't let your program execution return from `main()`. Always have an endless loop in your `main()`.

```
int main() {
    // initializations & one time tasks
    while (1) {
        // Tasks you need to do forever
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with what you said so +1, it's worth noting though that on the Cortex M4 `nop` aren't necessarily time consuming, they can be removed from the pipeline before execution, I use an `ISB` instruction rather than a `nop` here.

Comment: @Colin , Errata also mentions `DSB` instruction. Can we use any of `ISB` or `DSB` in this situation? Will single `DSB` or `ISB` do instead of 2  `NOP`s

Comment: A `DSB` should be fine too.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the startup code initializes the peripheral clocks for GPIOD peripheral, writing to GPIOD peripheral registers is useless.

Use working examples and perhaps use CubeIDE instead of Keil, or at least let CubeMX to generate a working project base for you to compile in Keil.

Comment: Hello Just me,I am doing the startup in RCC->AHB1ENR|=(1uL<<3);  line  shown bellow.,port D is at that bus.still nothing

#include "stm32f407xx.h"

int main()
{ //RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN
 RCC->AHB1ENR|=(1uL<<3); //set third bit to enable AHB1 BUS
 GPIOD->MODER&=~(1uL<<31);//reset 0 on 31 01 to gpio_moder 31,30 bits in register 
 GPIOD->MODER|=(1uL<<30);//set 1 on 30 output mode for pin 15 port D
 
 GPIOD->OTYPER=0; //all register is push pull
 GPIOD->OSPEEDR=0;//speed low
 GPIOD->ODR|=(1<<15); //Sets pin 15 as high
 
 
}

Comment: @ron398 *Edit your question* to add these additional details. They're no use down here in the comments on an answer.

Comment: I'll second the recommendation to use CubeIDE instead of Keil, at least when starting out.  You can have a blinking LED in a few minutes even using FreeRTOS.  Use that as a baseline and then branch out on your own after you gain some more understanding.